# simple preg_match help needed

Tags: php, preg-match

I am very new to php and need someone help. From the code below, I want the line **"I am a good boy"** but it prints "I am a good boy::None::She is a good girl"

```
$data = "None::I am a good boy::None::She is a good girl::None::";

$pattern = "/None::(.*)::None::/";
preg_match($pattern, $data, $results);
echo $results[1];
```

and in another one, I want **"2015-06-02 10:13:54"** but I get "015-06-02 10:13:54"

```
$data2 = "::2015-06-02 10:13:54::None::";

$pattern2 = "/::\d(.*)::None::/";
preg_match($pattern2, $data2, $results);
echo $results[1];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit change in `preg_match`:-

```
    <?php  
       $data = "None::I am a good boy::None::She is a good girl::None::";

       $pattern = "/None::(.*?)::None::/"; // ? is added to capture anything present between None:: and  ::None::
       preg_match($pattern, $data, $results);
       echo $results[1];


       $data2 = "::2015-06-02 10:13:54::None::";

       $pattern2 = "/::(.*?)::None::/"; // removed \d to remove digit restriction and added ? to capture anything present between :: and  ::None::
       preg_match($pattern2, $data2, $results);
       echo $results[1];
    ?>
```

Output:- https://eval.in/388254

Comment: You still didn't explain what the `?` actually does here

Answer (score 1):

Try these patterns.

```
$pattern = "/None::(.*?)::None::/";


$pattern2 = "/::(.*?)::None::/";
```